# What is the difference between ''and' logical operator and "&" bitwise operator in this case of Python?

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I have 2 cases in Python:
1) Case 1:

```
print "AND :", exists("") and os.path.getsize("")
```

This case will give a result: `AND : False`

2) Case 2:

```
print "Bitwise :", exists("") & os.path.getsize("")
```

This case will yield an error as following:

```
Bitwise :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Dropbox\Workspace_Python\PyGUI\default\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    print "Bitwise :", exists("") & os.path.getsize("")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\genericpath.py", line 49, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: ''
```

Can you help me to explain what is the difference between 2 these cases?

Answer (score 4):

In *logical `and` operator, if the first expression is falsey it will not evaluate the second expression*. Since `exists("")` fails, `os.path.getsize("")` is never executed in the first case.

But in the *bitwise `&` operator's case, both the operands have to evaluated*, to get the result. And since you cannot `stat` an invalid file (to get the size) it fails with an error.

Quoting from the [Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) docs,

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Also note that,

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true.

So, when you evaluated

```
exists("") and os.path.getsize("")
```

`exists("")` returned `False` and as per the above quoted text, it will immediately return `False`, without having to execute `os.path.getsize("")`.

Comment: Thanks for your correct answer to me. The point here is "short-circuit"

Comment: @LongUni : Yes, the _main_ point is that the Python boolean / logical operators can short-circuit, but for design reasons the bitwise operators do not. It can sometimes be convenient to use bitwise ops on boolean values, eg `a &= b` but generally it's stylistically better to use the boolean ops when manipulating boolean values and to only use bitwise ops when you are actually manipulating bits.

Answer (score 0):

As in most languages, *logical* ANDs will ["short-circuit"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and immediately abort if the first argument is false (because regardless of the second argument, the result is the same).

In your example, if you flipped the binary AND (`and`) to an OR (`or`), the language cannot short-circuit, because the first result is false and it needs to check the second to see if it should return true or false on the whole.